# Column is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I'm trying to select the latest date and group by name and keep other columns.

For example:

```
        name  status  date
        -----------------------
         a    l       13/19/04
         a    n       13/09/05
         a    dd      13/18/03
         b    l       13/01/01
         b    dd      13/01/02
         b    n       13/01/03
```

and I want the result like:

```
        name status date
        -----------------
          a    n      13/09/05
          b    n      13/01/03
```

Here's my code

```
SELECT
    Name,
    MAX(DATE) as Date,
    Status
FROM
    [ST].[dbo].[PS_RC_STATUS_TBL] 
GROUP BY 
    Name
```

I know that I should put max(status) because There are a lot of possibilities in each case, and nothing in the query makes it clear which value to choose for status in each group. Is there anyway to use inner join ?

Comment: try adding name & status in Group By

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Vinayak & @J W but it displays some deplucate values.

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear to me you want the max or min status.  Rather it seems to me you want the name and status as of a date certain.  That is, you want the rows with the lastest date for each name.  So ask for that:

```
select * from PS_RC_STATUS_TBL as T
where exists (
      select 1 from PS_RC_STATUS_TBL
      where name = T.name
      group by name
      having max(date) = T.date
)
```

Another way to think about it is

```
select T.* 
from PS_RC_STATUS_TBL as T
join (
      select name, max(date)  as date
      from PS_RC_STATUS_TBL
      group by name
) as D
on T.name = D.name
and T.date = D.date
```

Comment: Thank you very much ! What I want is the rows with the latest date for each name and join it to the rest of columns (in this case status I'm not interested in that column at all but I need to display it)! Well my problem is solved now thanks a lot :) !

Answer (score 1):

It just means that you need to put all *non-aggregated* columns in the `GROUP BY` clause, so in the case you need to put the other one

```
Select  Name , 
        MAX(DATE) as Date ,
        Status
FROM    [ST].[dbo].[PS_RC_STATUS_TBL] PS
Group   by Name, Status
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Vinayak & @J W but it displays some deplucate values.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server needs to know what to do with the rows that you are not grouping on (it has multiple rows to show on 1 line - so how?).  If you have aggregated on them (`MIN`, `MAX`, `AVG`, etc) then you are telling it what to do with these rows.  If not it will not know what to do - and will give you an error like the one you are getting.

From what you are saying though - it sounds like you do **not** want to group by the status.  It sounds like you are not interested in that column at all.  Let me know If that assumption is wrong.

```
SELECT
    Name,
    MAX(Date) AS 'Date',
FROM
    PS_RC_STATUS_TBL
GROUP BY
    Name
```

If you really do want the status, but don't want to group on it - try this:

```
SELECT 
    MyTable1.Name,
    MyTable2.Status,
    MyTable1.Date
FROM
   (SELECT Name, MAX(Date) AS 'Date' FROM PS_RC_STATUS_TBL GROUP BY Name) MyTable1
     INNER JOIN 
   (SELECT Name, Date, Status FROM PS_RC_STATUS_TBL) MyTable2
     ON MyTable1.Name = MyTable2.Name 
    AND MyTable1.Date = MyTable2.Date
```

That gives the exact results you've asked for - so does the method below using a CTE.

OR

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT Name, MAX(Date) AS Date 
      FROM PS_RC_STATUS_TBL
  GROUP BY Name)

SELECT cte.Name,
       tbl.Status,
       cte.Date
  FROM cte INNER JOIN 
     PS_RC_STATUS_TBL tbl ON cte.Name = tbl.Name 
                         AND cte.Date = tbl.Date
```

[SQLFiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f708d/7).

Comment: Thank you yes your assumption is totally true, the second query fits my need :) !

Answer (score 1):

This is a common problem with text fields in SQL aggregation scenarios. Using either MAX(Status) or MIN(Status) in your field list is a solution, usually MAX(Status) because of the lexical ordering:

```
"" < " " < "a"
```

In cases where you really need a more detailed ordering:

- Join to a StatusOrder relation **(*Status, OrderSequence)** in your main query;
- select **Max(OrderSequence)** in your aggregated query; and
- Join back to your StatusOrder relation on **OrderSequence** to select the correct Status value for display.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever fields you're selecting other than aggregation function, need to mention in group by clause.

```
SELECT 

gf.app_id,
ma.name as name,
count(ma.name) as count

FROM [dbo].[geo_fen_notification_table]  as gf 
inner join dbo.mobile_applications as ma on gf.app_id = ma.id

GROUP BY app_id,name
```

Here im accessing app_id and name in select, so i need to mention that after group by clause. otherwise it will throw error.